# How many values can be stored in $_COOKIE[] on the client for a website?

Tags: php, cookies

Can I store as many as values in setcookie? What's the limit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, the maximum size of a cookie depends on the browser.

See [RFC 2965](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2965.html)

> 5.1 Implementation Limits
>
> - at least 300 cookies
> - at least 4096 bytes per cookie (as measured by the characters that
>     comprise the cookie non-terminal in
>     the syntax description of the
>     Set-Cookie2 header, and as received in
>     the Set-Cookie2 header)
> - at least 20 cookies per unique host or domain name

/edit: Another interesting [Post](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2008/05/17/browser-cookie-restrictions/)

> - IE7/8 is 50 Cookies per Domain and 4095 Characters for name, value and equal sign
> - Firefox 50 Cookies and 4097 Characters
> - Opera 50 Cookies and 4096 Characters
> - Safari/WebKit unlimited Cookies and 4097 Characters

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, you can store about 4kb. Thus, you can use setcookie to store about that much stuff.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306070

Comment: The article only applies to IE up to 5.5

Answer (score 0):

Something different, whenever you ask this kind of question, there's probably a design problem. Better make use of the server-supplied session object or store some unique identifier in the cookie which you associate with the data which is stored server-side in some sort of database. This way you end up with only one cookie with "unlimited" information.